# launching urdf model from Gazebo1.7.6+ROS Fuerte

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to spawn any models through Gazebo1.7.6+ROS Fuerte.
But gazebo does not spawn anything. Here is my sequence.

1. roscore
2. roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
3. rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `pwd`/desk1.model -gazebo -z 1 -model box

From (3), just waiting with following message,

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1356233674.397032] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model
```

From (2), I got

```
... logging to /home/pidi/.ros/log/d4a6155e-4cae-11e2-ba92-9c4e36943400/roslaunch-pidi7-8753.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pidi7:47191/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [8773]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.2.5
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [8780]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.2.5
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:358] Converting a deprecatd SDF source[/home/pidi/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
  Version[1.0] to Version[1.2]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Warning [Converter.cc:191] Deprecated SDF Values in original file:
<background rgba='0.5 0.5 0.5 1'

Warning [Converter.cc:191] Deprecated SDF Values in original file:
<background

Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [1356232460.536994870]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1356232462.211541328, 0.001000000]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
[ INFO] [1356232462.234273210, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1356232462.262465099, 0.050000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
Warning [parser.cc:374] Gazebo SDF has no <gazebo> element in file[data-string]
Error [World.cc:1190] Unable to read sdf string
```

As long as I comfirmed through rosservice list, '/gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model' service exists.
I also tried many other urdf files, but results are same.

I also followed http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/SpawningObjectInSimulation, but it was also same.

Does anybody have idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/560/launching-urdf-model-from-gazebo1.7.6+ros-fuerte/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2012-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe the spawn_model script did not shown an appropriate error on failure. You are using a URDF (-urdf), but you have told the spawn_model script to expect a Gazebo SDF file (-gazebo). Try running:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file pwd/desk1.model -urdf -z 1 -model box
```

You can edit/update your original question in case this does not work.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) with karma: 138 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0